# Media queries не переписывает стили для абсолютно позиционируемого блока

Tags: вёрстка, media-queries, position

Есть блок у которого задано:

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
```

В @media хочу присвоить:

```
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
```

"top" срабатывает.
"left" нет.

Comment: Вы уверенны что там у вас в основных стилях нет !important для left  (может в другом месте)

Comment: Так не бывает. Создайте здесь сниппет, и вы увидите, что работает

Comment: !important точно нету.

Comment: В браузере посмотрите, в вычисленных стилях, какой left. А потом нажмите на стрелку рядом, чтобы понять, откуда он такой. Ну вот так (пример на другом правиле, но не важно): http://take.ms/fwESn

Answer (score 0):

Все заработало, когда я в @media поставил полный путь к блоку, а раньше был задан только частичный.

Comment: Конечно. Почитайте про специфичность тут: http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie